Is $f(x) = \sin x$ the unique function satisfying all five: $f(0)=0;\ f'(0)=1;\ f(\pi/2)=1;\ f'(\pi/2)=0;\ -1\leq f''(x)\leq 0$ for $x\in [0,\pi/2] ?$
I would like to prove or find a counter-example to the following proposition (which I came up with), please.

Suppose $f:[0,\pi/2]\to [0,1]$ is twice differentiable in the
interval $[0,\pi/2]$. Suppose further that,

$f(0) = 0;$
$f'(0) = 1;$
$f(\pi/2) = 1;$
$f'(\pi/2) = 0.$

Then, if $-1\leq f''(x)\leq 0$ for $x\in [0,\pi/2],$ then $f(x) = \sin
 x.$

I think if we did not impose the condition that $-1\leq f''(x)\leq 0$ for $x\in [0,\pi/2],$ then I think we can find a counter-example like: $f(x)$ is convex - i.e. $f''(x)>0$ - on $[0,0.1]$, and then concave all the way to the point $(\pi/2,1).$
I first tried supposing that $f(x)$ is a quadratic, and got a contradiction, so no quadratics satisfy the first four conditions.
I then tried supposing that $f(x)$ is a cubic, and determined that the only cubic satisfying the first four conditions is,
$$ f(x) = \frac{4\pi-16}{\pi^3}x^3 + \frac{12 - 4\pi}{\pi^2} x^2 + x, $$
but then $f''(\pi/2) = -1.158\ldots < -1.$ So we can rule out cubics also.
I'm not sure quite where to go from here, other than more tedious calculations trying quartics, quintics etc. Does anyone have the answer to this question off hand, or have any ideas for a counter-example or an affirmative proof of the proposition by contradiction?

There any many more functions than just the polynomials.

@badjohn Sure, but do you have an idea of a function in mind? Or, an idea of the shape of the graph of the function compared with $\sin x$?

Actually yeah, there should be some function whose 2nd derivative is $-1$ on some interval like $[\pi/2-0.1, \pi/2],$ and then it joins up nicely to the line $y=x$ somewhere around $x=0.3$ without breaking any of the five conditions.

You can take $$f(x) = \sin(x)+g(x)$$
where $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1000}\cos^4(4x)& \text{ if } \tfrac{\pi}{8}<x<\tfrac{3\pi}{8}\\
0& \text{ otherwise }\\
\end{cases}$$
as a counterexample.

@AnneBauval The downvote was mine. Take a look at the edit history.

@jjagmath I checked that $g$ is twice differentiable but your answer would be more reader-friendly if you did it explicitely.
